# Prove $f$ is derivable and find $f'(0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm stuck solving the following problem:

---

**Problem:** Prove there exists an unique function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$2(f(x))^3 - 3(f(x))^2 + 6f(x) = x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Also prove $f$ is derivable in $\mathbb{R}$ and calculate $f'(0)$.

---

I have been able to prove the existence and uniqueness (see below) but I don't know how to prove $f$ is derivable or calculate $f'(0)$.

**How can I prove it?**

---

*Proof of existence and uniqueness:*

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The equation

$$2x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x = a \qquad (\ast)$$

has at least one solution since $p(x) = 2x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x$ is an odd-degree polynomial.

Suppose there were two different solutions $x_1, x_2$ for $(\ast)$. Then, by Rolle's theorem there exists $c \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that:

$$p'(c) = 6x^2 - 6x + 6 = 0$$

But $\Delta_{p'} = 6^2 - 4 \cdot 6^2 < 0$, so $p'(c) = 0$ has no real solutions, which is a contradiction. Hence, there exists an unique solution for $(\ast)$.

Finally, we can define $f(a) = x$, where $x$ is the solution to $(\ast)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you already proved existence *and uniqueness* by showing **that cubic** fulfills the condition ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the inverse function theorem?

Comment: @Timbuc Yes, I will edit my answer to include the proof.

Comment: @mlainz Wouldn't I need to prove $f$ is derivable first?

Comment: @Timbuc I have updated my answer including the proof of existence and uniqueness. If something is wrong please let me know.

Comment: No. You have to prove that $x(y)= 2y^3-3y^2+ 6 y$ is differentiable, which is trivial. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem.

Comment: @mlainz I think you can use it to solve the problem, thank you! I will not answer myself yet in case you want to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $p(f)=2f^3-3f^2+6f$ since $p'(f)>0$ then by [Inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) $p$ is invertible and $p^{-1}$ is differentiable and we have:
$$f(x)=p^{-1} (x)$$
For calculate $f'$, we derive from both sides of $2(f(x))^3 - 3(f(x))^2 + 6f(x) = x$ then we achieve this equation:
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{6(f(x)^2 - f(x)+1)}$$ 
If  $z$ is real root of $p(f)=0$ then $f'(0)=\frac{1}{6(z^2-z+1)}$ and because $z=0$ then $f'(0)=\frac{1}{6}$.

> Generalization:
>   If $g(f(x))$ and $h(x)$ are real functions such that $g'(f(x))>0$ and $ h'(x)>0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R$ now if we have $g(f(x))=h(x)$ then $f(x)$ is differentiable well-defined function.

Comment: This does not prove anything!

Comment: I was going to mark this answer as accepted but I think you need to clarify why it suffices to prove $f(x)^2 - f(x) + 1 \neq 0$ for proving derivability and why this is obvious.

Comment: This is obvious because $x^2-x+1=0$ have no any real root. and if $f(x)^2 - f(x)+1 \neq 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $f'(x)$ exist for all $x \in \mathbb{R} $( from above equation for$ f'(x)$ ).

Comment: If I have not understood you incorrectly I think you are implicitly using the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). I think you should state it in your proof.

Comment: When we have a formula for $f'(x)$ for all $x$, then we can calculate $f'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, and we don't have need anything more!

Comment: We use "Inverse function theorem" when we haven't any explicit formula for $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I will accept your solution as correct as it is clearer than the other. Nonetheless I am not entirely convinced you are not using the theorem.

Comment: I have a question: for example anyone say that $f'(x)=1/g(x)$ and $g(x)$ is well-defined function on $\mathbb R$ such that  $ g(x) \neq 0 $ for all $x$. then it's not true that we conclude $f$ is derivable?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24810/discussion-between-psi-and-2000).

Comment: @ mookid: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueness comes from, for any $x$,

$$2f^3-3f^2+6f=2g^3-3g^2+6g,$$or
$$(f-g)\left(2(f^2+fg+g^2)-3(f+g)+6\right)=0.$$

Solving $2f^2+(2g-3)f+2g^2-3g+6$ for $f$, the discriminant is
$$(2g-3)^2-4(2g^2-3g+6)=-4g^2-15,$$
so that there is no other real solution than $f=g$.

---

For $x=0$, $2f^3-3f^2+6f=f(2f^2-3f+6)=0$ has the single real solution $f=0$.

Then $f'\left(6f^2-6f+6\right)=1$, and $f'(0)=\dfrac16.$

As $6f^2-6f+6$ has no real roots, the derivative is always defined.

Comment: Nice uniqueness proof! In the second part does $f = f(0)$ and $f' = f'(0)$?

Comment: @Psi As you guessed.